# C++ generic template

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Hello all i am just beginning to learn c++ and just looked at templates. I was asked to make a template function print that would take an array and a int input and print out the elements in the array. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void print(T a[], int b)
{
     for(int y=0; y < b; y++)
     {
        cout << a[y] <<" ";
     }

}

int main()
{

int arr[5];
int size = sizeof(arr);

for(int h=0; h<=size; h++)
{
    arr[h]=0;
}

print(arr,size);

}
```

The program compiles with no errors but when I run it there is no output. Can anyone help? or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the value of the variable `size`.

```
int size = sizeof(arr);
```

gives the size of the array in *bytes*, it is not 5.

```
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

will give the right answer.

It would also be a good idea to add

```
cout << endl;
```

at the end of main.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not aware of that!

Answer (score 2):

Your program has [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior%E2%80%8E) at this point:

```
for (int h = 0; h <= size; h++)
{
    arr[h] = 0;
}
```

You defined `size` to be the number of bytes held in the array `arr`, not the actual number of integers present. Therefore, an integer on your platform is most likely greater than 1 byte, so `size` will be equal to a number far greater than 5.

And when you do `arr[h]`, you're eventually going to access an address beyond the bounds of the array. It is at that point that your program contracts a case of Undefined Behavior. At that moment, anything in your program can happen, including the output not appearing.

The fix to this problem is to divide the bytes present in `arr` by the size in bytes of a single `int`. That will tell you the number of elements:

```
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
```

An even better solution is to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) so that the size is known and can be accessed through its member function `size`:

```
std::array<int, 5> arr{{}};

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
    arr[i] = 0;
```

<sub>Note that using [*aggregate-initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization%E2%80%8E) on `std::array` causes zero-initialization of each element. Thus, there is no use for the subsequent for loop.</sub>

You'll also need to adapt your function so that it can access an array object:

```
template<typename T, unsigned N>
void print(const std::array<T, N>& a)
{
    for (const auto& x : a) // range-based for loop
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of this behavior, thanks for the in depth explanation!